# Photoshop Extremely slow with shapes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, shapes

I have an issue with shapes in my photoshop and it persists across versions and installs.

Basically whenever I create a new vector shape, it will take multiple seconds to create one. The waiting time is slower the larger the shape is. I don't believe this is the intended behaviour.

A video of this issue is here: https://imgur.com/a/aiuRUbV

The document size is relatively small (512x512px) in the video, but still creating a hexagon takes around five seconds. If the document were to be larger, it would take even more.

I don't think it is a hardware issue since I do have RTX 4080 & Ryzen 9 7959x with 64gb DDR5 ram.

My performance settings in photoshop are as follows:
[image: Photoshop performance settings]

Comment: Sorry, tech support is off topic. You may need to contact Adobe.

Comment: That sounds very strange, PS should not do this with your hardware.